# How do I fix a broken nipple under my sprinkler head?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I removed a broken sprinkler from my front yard.  Apparently, whoever installed (previous owner) it did not thread it properly; the threaded nipple snapped off. What do I need to do?  How do I replace the nipple?  I see a white nut.  Do I need to remove that and get a new nipple, or is it more involved?

Answer (score 3):

A picture would make it easier to help, but I would guess the white "nut" you see is probably the PVC female adapter that is glued to the pipe.

[image]

If you can do it, the fastest fix is to unthread the nipple from inside the hub, then just replace it with a new nipple.

If you can't do that, you'll have to cut the adapter off, and then glue a new one on (PVC glue is permanent -- once it sets, it's never coming apart). If there is enough room you can just glue a new adapter on, and then get a slightly longer nipple to keep the sprinkler head at the same height.

If there's not enough room, you may need to dig it up some more, cut the elbow or T below off, and replace everything.